# calculate overlapping areas

Tags: area, geopandas, convex-hull

I am following the example [here](https://geopandas.org/geometric_manipulations.html) and successfully created convex hulls. But I have a question on how to calculate the shared areas between each convex hull in the following figure:
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example to get the intersection of Manhattan and the Bronx. You could use pd.concat() before .overlay() if you want to combine boroughs.

```
import geopandas as gpd
nybb_path = gpd.datasets.get_path('nybb')

boros = gpd.read_file(nybb_path)
boros.set_index('BoroCode', inplace=True)
boros.sort_index(inplace=True)

boros['geometry'] = boros['geometry'].convex_hull

print(boros)
    BoroName    Shape_Leng  Shape_Area  geometry
BoroCode                
1   Manhattan   359299.096471   6.364715e+08    POLYGON ((977855.445 188082.322, 971830.134 19...
2   Bronx   464392.991824   1.186925e+09    POLYGON ((1017949.978 225426.885, 1015563.562 ...
3   Brooklyn    741080.523166   1.937479e+09    POLYGON ((988872.821 146772.032, 983670.606 14...
4   Queens  896344.047763   3.045213e+09    POLYGON ((1000721.532 136681.776, 994611.996 2...
5   Staten Island   330470.010332   1.623820e+09    POLYGON ((915517.688 120121.881, 915467.035 12...

manhattan_gdf = boros.iloc[0:1, :]
bronx_gdf = boros.iloc[1:2, :]

manhattan_bronx_intersecetion_polygon = gpd.overlay(manhattan_gdf, bronx_gdf, 
how='intersection')

#SPCS83 New York Long Island zone (US Survey feet)
print(manhattan_bronx_intersecetion_polygon.geometry[0].area)
164559574.89341027

ax = manhattan_bronx_intersecetion_polygon.plot(figsize=(6,6))
boros.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='none', edgecolor='k');
```

[image]

Here is a loop solution like you asked for in your comment.

```
import geopandas as gpd
nybb_path = gpd.datasets.get_path('nybb')

boros = gpd.read_file(nybb_path)
boros.set_index('BoroCode', inplace=True)
boros.sort_index(inplace=True)

boros['geometry'] = boros['geometry'].convex_hull

intersection_polygons_list = []

for idx, row in boros.iterrows():

    main_boro_gdf = boros.iloc[idx-1:idx, :]

    print('\n' + 'main boro:', main_boro_gdf['BoroName'].values.tolist()[:])

    other_boro_list = boros.index.tolist()

    other_boro_list.remove(idx)

    other_boro_gdf = boros[boros.index.isin(other_boro_list)]

    print('other boros:',other_boro_gdf['BoroName'].values.tolist()[:])

    intersection_polygons = gpd.overlay(main_boro_gdf, other_boro_gdf, how='intersection')

    intersection_polygons['intersection_area'] = intersection_polygons.geometry.area

    print('intersecton area sum:', intersection_polygons['intersection_area'].sum())

    intersection_polygons_list.append(intersection_polygons)
```

output:

```
main boro: ['Manhattan']
other boros: ['Bronx', 'Brooklyn', 'Queens', 'Staten Island']
intersecton area sum: 279710750.6116526

main boro: ['Bronx']
other boros: ['Manhattan', 'Brooklyn', 'Queens', 'Staten Island']
intersecton area sum: 216638786.2669542

main boro: ['Brooklyn']
other boros: ['Manhattan', 'Bronx', 'Queens', 'Staten Island']
intersecton area sum: 1506573115.3550038

main boro: ['Queens']
other boros: ['Manhattan', 'Bronx', 'Brooklyn', 'Staten Island']
intersecton area sum: 1560297426.3563197

main boro: ['Staten Island']
other boros: ['Manhattan', 'Bronx', 'Brooklyn', 'Queens']
intersecton area sum: 0.0
```

You can plot using the intersection_polygons_list index values. For example here are the overlapping areas for the Bronx:

```
intersection_polygons_list[1].plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly. How can I create a loop to calculate all the shared areas among the five convex hulls on the condition that they share some common areas?

Comment: Absolutely, it works perfectly. Thanks. I am not familiar with loop in Python, so it takes a while for me to figure out what exactly each step is doing. I was trying to convert the list to pandas DataFrame using `df = pd.DataFrame(intersection_polygons_list)`, but the results are not what I am looking for. Could you please help me out how to convert the list to a pandas DataFrame properly, like include it inside the loop. Much Appreciated!

Comment: You can just do df = (intersection_polygons_list[0]) using the list index values of 0-4.

Comment: Yeah, I did that by converting each element to five DFs, then append them. But what if the list has more elements. A loop is more efficient for doing this, like looping from 0 to `len(intersection_polygons_list)`. Again, I am new to loop in Python, I have not figured out how to do that in a loop.

Comment: Use pd.concat() if you want one big df of all the intersections concat_df = pd.concat(intersection_polygons_list).

Comment: Thanks. Much appreciated!

Comment: Hi, just wondering if you can spare some time to give a look at this example. Thanks. Much appreciated! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61801681/intersect-polygons-based-on-if-conditions-on-column-values